# how do i bind data from a json array in knocketout.js?

Tags: data-binding, view, knockout.js, viewmodel, knockout-2.0

i have the code for View and the ViewModel below and some how the data is not binding to the view

http://jsfiddle.net/vZdJz/

should the data be of a specific format?

how about if the json is in the following format

```
{
  "0": {1,2,3},
  "1": {2,3,4},
  "2": {3,4,5},
  "3": {4,5,6}
}
```

instead of the following array

```
[
  {1,2,3},
  {2,3,4},
  {3,4,5},
  {4,5,6}
]
```

any help is greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you have a few syntax errors. First, checkboxes need to use the `checked` binding, not the `value` binding. You also have an element with two data-bind attributes, which is invalid. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZdJz/4/) to see a working version (I stripped out the unused properties, they were cluttering things). You should also note that binding a checkbox to an `id` property isn't going to make a lot of sense.

Note, I am using Knockout2.0, which jsfiddle has a framework for. I was still getting an error when using the latest version you were linking to. I wasn't able to figure out why, especially considering it works with 2.0.